# Python: regex a string with a wildcard in it

Tags: python, full-text-search, escaping, wildcard

What I would like to do is to allow the user to input something such as:  "Torsion ? Group", wildcard and all (the wildcard being a whole word) and a true or false returned depending on whether found or not.  So would I have something such as \b*\b? The Python manual says that \bfoo\b will match strings of the form "something foo something else" as well as "foo.".  the issue that I am having is that I am even trying to start simple modifying another example I found:

```
inputstring = 'What is a Torsion Abelian Group (TAB)?' 
str1 = "Abelian"
output = re.search("Torsion" + \bstr1\b + "Group", inputstring)
print output
```

I however get the output:

```
output = re.search("Torsion" + \bstr1\b + "Group", inputstring)
                                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Thus I am having difficulties finding a known string, let alone a wildcard.  Any thoughts on either would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python will not know what to do with your two `\b`, and will assume that you have a variable named `\bstr1\b`, and not `str1`. You will need to separate the `\b` and `str1`, and wrap the regex syntax with quotation marks or remove them. You should also double check [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to make sure that  `\b` is the syntax that you should be using.

```
output = re.search("Torsion " + str1 + " Group", inputstring)
```

Or cleaner

```
output = re.search("Torsion %s Group" % str1, inputstring)
```

This is the full code:

```
inputstring = 'What is a Torsion Abelian Group (TAB)?'
str1 = "Abelian"
output = re.search("Torsion %s Group" % str1, inputstring)
if output:
    print str(output.group(0))
```

And returns the following output:

```
Torsion Abelian Group
```

Comment: Thanks eanderson.  The first solution you propose, that of with the \b's removed returns <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb725cfa8> I am guessing this is a reference?  If so do you know how to pull the object at that location?  The second solution works and I think I understand how it works - it is pretty straight forward as %s is getting replaced by str1. As for the /b syntax and link you gave (good link thanks), it looks like it is supposed to work as it is said to "match whole words only".  I don't know why my example above is not working. Note the error ^ was not originally pointing to /b but )

Comment: Do you want the regex to match part of a string, but return the whole string if a match? As for the return that is indeed the référence. Take a look at the full example. I had the same issue with \b, not sure if that is caused by an issue with python, or us not understanding the regex.

Comment: But the question really comes down to what you want returned from the regex when you find a match.